# Exclude domains and file types with wget

Tags: shell, wget

I've found a lot of information about it, but I haven't been able to get wget to exclude domains and file extensions.

I have a .txt file that has many urls. I want to avoid downloading images (jpg, png, gif) of certain domains and also avoid downloading html or links files.

Using the following command I downloaded everything inside file.txt

```
wget -i file.txt
```

In file I have the following urls

```
https://feedly.com/
http://img2.rtve.es/v/3195388?w=1600&preview=1435846554460.jpg
https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/127855/isolated/preview/c3f01cf799e4c8714a815fac05820bea-reloj-despertador-plana-verde-by-vexels.png
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif
```

To exclude domains I tried `wget -i file.txt --exclude-domains img2.rtve.es`. The result are without errors

```
wget -i file.txt --exclude-domains img2.rtve.es
--2018-05-18 16:29:54--  https://feedly.com/
Resolving feedly.com... 104.20.60.241, 104.20.59.241
Connecting to feedly.com|104.20.60.241|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html              [ <=>                ]  15.45K  --.-KB/s    in 0.03s   

2018-05-18 16:29:55 (616 KB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [15821]

--2018-05-18 16:29:55--  http://img2.rtve.es/v/3195388?w=1600&preview=1435846554460.jpg
Resolving img2.rtve.es... 8.252.16.124, 8.253.165.245, 8.253.48.245
Connecting to img2.rtve.es|8.252.16.124|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 87358 (85K) [image/jpeg]
Saving to: ‘3195388?w=1600&preview=1435846554460.jpg’

3195388?w=1600&prev 100%[===================>]  85.31K   552KB/s    in 0.2s    

2018-05-18 16:29:56 (552 KB/s) - ‘3195388?w=1600&preview=1435846554460.jpg’ saved [87358/87358]

--2018-05-18 16:29:56--  https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/127855/isolated/preview/c3f01cf799e4c8714a815fac05820bea-reloj-despertador-plana-verde-by-vexels.png
Resolving images.vexels.com... 177.54.152.45
Connecting to images.vexels.com|177.54.152.45|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 9957 (9.7K) [image/png]
Saving to: ‘c3f01cf799e4c8714a815fac05820bea-reloj-despertador-plana-verde-by-vexels.png’

c3f01cf799e4c8714a8 100%[===================>]   9.72K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2018-05-18 16:29:56 (69.8 MB/s) - ‘c3f01cf799e4c8714a815fac05820bea-reloj-despertador-plana-verde-by-vexels.png’ saved [9957/9957]

--2018-05-18 16:29:56--  https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif
Resolving upload.wikimedia.org... 208.80.154.240
Connecting to upload.wikimedia.org|208.80.154.240|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1429302 (1.4M) [image/gif]
Saving to: ‘Rotating_earth_(large).gif’

Rotating_earth_(lar 100%[===================>]   1.36M  1.00MB/s    in 1.4s    

2018-05-18 16:29:58 (1.00 MB/s) - ‘Rotating_earth_(large).gif’ saved [1429302/1429302]

FINISHED --2018-05-18 16:29:58--
Total wall clock time: 4.1s
Downloaded: 4 files, 1.5M in 1.5s (978 KB/s)
```

And to exclude extensions `wget -i file.txt --reject gif`. The result are without errors

```
MacBook-Pro:test tomillo$ wget -i file.txt --reject gif
--2018-05-18 16:34:28--  https://feedly.com/
Resolving feedly.com... 104.20.59.241, 104.20.60.241
Connecting to feedly.com|104.20.59.241|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html              [ <=>                ]  15.45K  --.-KB/s    in 0.04s   

2018-05-18 16:34:30 (429 KB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [15821]

--2018-05-18 16:34:30--  http://img2.rtve.es/v/3195388?w=1600&preview=1435846554460.jpg
Resolving img2.rtve.es... 8.252.16.124, 8.253.165.245, 8.253.149.117
Connecting to img2.rtve.es|8.252.16.124|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 87358 (85K) [image/jpeg]
Saving to: ‘3195388?w=1600&preview=1435846554460.jpg’

3195388?w=1600&prev 100%[===================>]  85.31K   566KB/s    in 0.2s    

2018-05-18 16:34:30 (566 KB/s) - ‘3195388?w=1600&preview=1435846554460.jpg’ saved [87358/87358]

--2018-05-18 16:34:30--  https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/127855/isolated/preview/c3f01cf799e4c8714a815fac05820bea-reloj-despertador-plana-verde-by-vexels.png
Resolving images.vexels.com... 177.54.152.175
Connecting to images.vexels.com|177.54.152.175|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 9957 (9.7K) [image/png]
Saving to: ‘c3f01cf799e4c8714a815fac05820bea-reloj-despertador-plana-verde-by-vexels.png’

c3f01cf799e4c8714a8 100%[===================>]   9.72K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2018-05-18 16:34:30 (74.2 MB/s) - ‘c3f01cf799e4c8714a815fac05820bea-reloj-despertador-plana-verde-by-vexels.png’ saved [9957/9957]

--2018-05-18 16:34:30--  https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif
Resolving upload.wikimedia.org... 208.80.154.240
Connecting to upload.wikimedia.org|208.80.154.240|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1429302 (1.4M) [image/gif]
Saving to: ‘Rotating_earth_(large).gif’

Rotating_earth_(lar 100%[===================>]   1.36M  1024KB/s    in 1.4s    

2018-05-18 16:34:32 (1024 KB/s) - ‘Rotating_earth_(large).gif’ saved [1429302/1429302]

FINISHED --2018-05-18 16:34:32--
Total wall clock time: 3.9s
Downloaded: 4 files, 1.5M in 1.6s (972 KB/s)
```

Where's the problem?

Comment: What happened when you tried excluding the domains/extensions?  Did it throw an error?  Did it download them anyways?  Please consider editing your question to include that information.

Comment: @Mr.Llama no errors. I have edited my question with results in terminal.